# TCPDF font tool: How to generate font files using OTF font type

Tags: php, tcpdf

When running the tcpdf_addfont.php tool for generating font files used by tcpdf

```
  php .\tcpdf_addfont.php -i HansomFY-Light_S.otf
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
  *** Output dir set to C:\xampp2\htdocs\vboxCode\flow-api\TCPDF-master/fonts/
  --- ERROR: can't add HansomFY-Light_S.otf
  --- Process completed with ERRORS!
```

Is it not possible to use otf for this tool?

Comment: Where does come from HansomFY-Light_S.otf ? is there any other error message ?

Comment: Hi @Frankich its the same folder with the tcpdf_addfont.php

Comment: Can you host your file somewhere, so that I can have a test on your font?

Comment: @Frankich I used the current version from Github, without modifying any codes. See the result yourself:  https://imgur.com/a/6VTJm3J . *My advice? Never say never.*

Comment: @bananaCute your problem is not related to converting the font to TTF. 1. it might be path problem (as you can see your path mix with slash and backslash); 2. The font integrity has problems (as I advised in comments earlier, you can check with font tools). *In short, TCPDF supports OTF format; converting to TTF is unnecessary.*

Comment: @Raptor how to check the font intigrety?

Comment: If you are using macOS, you can use the built-in FontBook app. for Windows, Microsoft has provided a tool to do similar work: https://github.com/microsoft/Font-Validator

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a font to support Chinese, apparently TCPDF doesn't support OpenType formats that use CFF data, I tried to convert the font to `.ttf` with `fontforge` but then `tcpdf_addfont` had problems converting with something missing in the font, I could use the font imported but the quality result was poor (like condensed), I had better results using [this python snippet](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools/blob/master/Snippets/otf2ttf.py) from [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools)

Comment: Awesome! Your suggestion was such a big help in my current problem with converting Noto Serif JP font to TCPDF font. There's only OTF available when downloading it from Google. So FontTools was a great help in converting the OTF to TTF without breaking the font. The Font converters I found online are all useless!